# Wrong number of items passed 2484, placement implies 1 Datafraime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Пример одной из таблиц с входными данными. Поля по таблице rates = [ASOF_DATE, CURRENCY_PAIR, RATE], assets = [ASSET_ID, TYPE, CURRENCY]]
Пример одной из таблиц с входными данными. Поля по таблице rates = [ASOF_DATE, CURRENCY_PAIR, RATE], assets = [ASSET_ID, TYPE, CURRENCY]
Задача: Рассчитать цену всех акций в евро
В результате моего кода должен создаваться столбец с ценами в евро "PRICE_EUR". Понимаю, что ошибка заключается в том, что код пытается запихнуть список в ячейку с одним значением, но не понимаю, почему он этот лист создаёт, когда вроде как должен выдаваться единственный результат.
В фрейме df2 хранятся курсы различных валют за каждый день 
Сам код:

```
import pandas as pd
excelFile = pd.ExcelFile('interview_data.xlsx')
#Переведём каждую таблицу в датафрейм
df1 = excelFile.parse('holdings') # таблица holdings = df1
df2 = excelFile.parse('rates') # таблица rates = df2
df3 = excelFile.parse('assets') # таблица assets = df3
#объединеним таблицы holdings и assets в единый датафрейм, как в прощлый раз
holdasset = df1.merge(df3, on='ASSET_ID', how='left')

def findEURprice(row, rates = df2):
    if row["CURRENCY"] == 'EUR':
        return row['PRICE']
    elif row["CURRENCY"] == 'USD':
        return row['PRICE']/rates[(rates['ASOF_DATE']==row['ASOF_DATE']) & 
(rates['CURRENCY_PAIR']=='EUR/USD')]['RATE']
    else:
        usd_jpy = row['PRICE']/rates[(rates['ASOF_DATE']==row['ASOF_DATE']) 
& (rates['CURRENCY_PAIR']=='USD/JPY')]['RATE']
        return (usd_jpy/rates[(rates['ASOF_DATE']==row['ASOF_DATE']) & 
(rates['CURRENCY_PAIR']=='EUR/USD')]['RATE'])

holdasset['PRICE_EUR'] = holdasset.apply(findEURprice, axis=1)
print(holdasset.head())
```

При выводе результата работы holdasset.apply(findEURprice, axis=1) показывается следующее:

```
        0     1     3     4     6     7     ...  3717  3718  3720  3721  3723  3724
```

0        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
...      ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
129795   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
129796   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
129797   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
129798   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
129799   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

[129800 rows x 2484 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0

Вопрос: почему создаётся список из 2484 результатов вместо одно значения?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных.  [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Вы можете выложить Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник? Сомневаюсь что кто-то захочет вбивать данные с картинки чтобы помочь вам...